# MVC session data access on SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

Does any one have an Idea when the values in the session are binded to it when your session state behavior is set to ReadOnly on your controller?

Session is set to InProc on web.config file:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="1440"></sessionState>
```

My controller has the SessionState attribute:

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
public class MyController : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
  ....
}
```

I am trying to catch the data stored in the session on:

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyClass usr = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["MySession"] as MyClass; //usr is always null

}
```

But when i set the session state behavior in the controller to Default:

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Default)]
public class MyController : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
  ....
}
```

I am able to retrieve the value on Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute block.

Comment: Can you explain when in the request process the session variable is set i.e. is it set in a prior request? I've mocked up a quick test and this seems to work OK, so it must be something about your implementation. Perhaps you could include an example of the controllers/actions and what order they are requested in.

Comment: @BrentMannering it is a pair of HttpPost and HttpGet actions. I have also have no Session.Clear on any of my codes.